# Numpy.int 32 object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I trained a model with keras and when i want to show the scores i get a numpy error on the prediction_cat line saying numpy.int32 object is not iterable. Any help would be great. Thank you.

This is the code of the cell:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, auc, f1_score, recall_score

prediction = model.predict(test_img_pca)

prediction_cat = [np.where(row == max(row))[0][0] for row in prediction]

acc_krr = accuracy_score(y_test_cat, prediction_cat)
print("Accuracy: ", acc_krr)

rcl_krr = recall_score(y_test_cat, prediction_cat, average = None)
print("Recall: ", rcl_krr)

f1_krr = f1_score(y_test_cat, prediction_cat, average = None)
print("F1: ", f1_krr)
```

And this is the error i get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14244\3875264768.py in <module>
      3 prediction = model.predict(test_img_pca)
      4 
----> 5 prediction_cat = [np.where(row == max(row))[0][0] for row in prediction]
      6 
      7 acc_krr = accuracy_score(y_test_cat, prediction_cat)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14244\3875264768.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 prediction = model.predict(test_img_pca)
      4 
----> 5 prediction_cat = [np.where(row == max(row))[0][0] for row in prediction]
      6 
      7 acc_krr = accuracy_score(y_test_cat, prediction_cat)

TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is telling you the `prediction` object is not an iterable and it cannot be manipulated by your list comprehension, but rather a `numpy.int32` type object.

try printing the `prediction` and see what it looks like to get a better idea of what it is

EDIT: the avove is wrong.

the issue is you cannot use `max()` in that way. `max()` can only be applied to iterables per the help:

```
Help on built-in function max in module builtins:

max(...)
    max(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
    max(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value
    
    With a single iterable argument, return its biggest item. The
    default keyword-only argument specifies an object to return if
    the provided iterable is empty.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
```

but you are applying it to a `numpy.int32`.

if what you want is to get the index of the highest value in the prediction array you will need to use `np.argmax` as shown [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Comment: The prediction variable is an array containing the labels the model has predicted

Comment: see my edit give your clarification